# Silverlight and URL Rewrite - do they play nice?

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a Silverlight application deployed behind the firewall using IIS7, and I would like to URL rewrite a public URL to access it. So http://someurl.com would rewrite to http://internalserver/Default.aspx, this is how I setup the rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WebSite_InboundRule" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://internalserver/Default.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

At this point (after changing some relative paths to absolute in the ASPX wrapper), the browser gets to the Default.aspx page from http://someurl.com, but then the page is blank and the Silverlight.js file is the last thing to Fiddler shows that was downloaded. Right-clicking on the page gives me the Silverlight context menu, so my guess is that the Silverlight plug-in loads up fine but for some reason it can't download the XAP file.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your xap url looks like? And looking at the rewrite rule it looks like you rewrite all incoming urls into http://internalserver/Default.aspx including request for xap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're rewriting all inbound URL's (including ones like http://someurl.com/MySilverlightApp.xap) to http://internalserver/Default.aspx.  Since that doesn't return a valid XAP file, it makes sense that your Silverlight app won't load. You need to add a rule that redirects requests for XAP files to the appropriate internal location of those XAP files.

Comment: I see, so the rewrite URL should be `http://internalserver/{R:0}` or something like that? I want everything after http://someurl.com to be appended to http://internalserver in this case.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure my previous comment is accurate. Please see my resonse to Denis' comment in the Question comments for clarification.